# Loading simples text file list on listview C#

Tags: c#, string, listview, text, listbox

so i was working with a text file data that contains a lot of simple lines and i want to put them on the list view exatly the same way as the listbox do. I need that because after i loading a long list on listbox, even it showing all my items, i cannot make a FindString() on it. i attached the comand to a combo box, and with other small lists it worked, but with this larger, seems that index reference doesn't work because of listbox limit.
   So i was wondering if is possible to put, as example:

- line1
- line2
- line3
- line4

My text files hasn't this dots, i pu them just to make the example vertical.
On a list view. i used on listbox the method file.readllines to get it loading to it, and if exists a string find method to help me get the text on the lines. What should i do?

Comment: what you have tried so far ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write the searcher you want by yourself.
It's very easy.
Just iterate on each data that exists in your ListView.
Then check your condition through an if-statement and do anything you want with the result!

Like this :

```
    this.listView1.Items.Add("Test1");
    this.listView1.Items.Add("Test2");

    int Index = 0;

    foreach (ListViewItem t in this.listView1.Items)
    {
         if (t.Text == "Test1")
            Index = t.SelectedIndex;
            break;
    }

    this.listView1.Items[Index].Selected = true;
```

I added couple of items to the ListView then iterate on it's items using a foreach, filter the items using an if-statement and finally show the item that I want.

Comment: thanks man, but how can i select a item in the listview with a string that correspond it?, like: listbox.selecteditem = "asdf";

Comment: I changed my answer to what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add an eventhandler. For example for the event of the ListView Load.
Then in the event handler you could load the contents of the file using the File class.

For example you could do it like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace WpfApplication2
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        // ListView Loaded - Eventhandler
        private void ListView_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
           string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("E:\\test.txt");
           foreach (string line in lines)
           {
               listview.Items.Add(line);
           }
        }
    }
}
```

I have just tested the solution and it works fine.
I hope I got your intention.

[image: Results]

Comment: thanks brow, but i'm with a problem, my net framework is 2.0 and i can't change it, so RoutedEventArgs doesn't exist, but even i putting your code in my form_load, the list view load the lines side by side in little boxes, not in list like your image, i will try to change some listview configuration from designer to be sure, thanks xD

Answer (score 0):

thanks a lot of helping me, but i gandle it, i search a lot for extending the limit of listbox but no one was capable to help me out, but with your "foreach" code, this new way to search helped me to select my string on listbox, here's the code using a combo box to evertime updated get me the selected value from a gourgeous list:

declaring:

```
string result;
```

and then the combobox event:

```
private void comboBox1_TextUpdate(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (string item in listBox1.Items)
        {
            listBox1.SelectionMode = SelectionMode.One;

                if (item == comboBox1.Text)
                {
                    result = item;
                }

        }
        listBox1.SelectedItem = result;

    }
```